# Running Python script in Task Scheduler-- Script will not run

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, windows

I have a script which I wish to run on a regular monthly basis without me needing to open and run the it.  I have referred to every web page I can find on Windows Task Scheduler and followed their instructions.  However, running the script from Task Scheduler will only open the script in Python and not run it.

In the Task Scheduler Run Window, I have tried entering both the path to the script alone and the path to the script with the path to my Python program.  I've also tried entering the path to my Python program as the script with my script as an argument as suggested [in this blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/07/30/scheduling-a-scrip/). My script is hard-coded, so I don't think I need to add any arguments.

Am I missing something obvious?

---

I was experiencing issues because I was using the path to the Python program and not the Python command line.  I.e., I was using "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\Pythonwin.exe" when I needed to be using "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\python.exe".

Comment: In [this](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/87614) post if you read the comments it looks like the OP was able to get it to run by using cmd as the program and the script as the argument.

Comment: Thank you.  I haven't seen this post yet.  I'll look it over and see if the information in it works for me.

Comment: And to whoever asked, I think I have 32 Python on a 64 machine.

Comment: So I tried the suggestion in the post you suggested, but I still don't seem to be having any luck.  I tried using cmd as the program with /c C:\Python27.exe G:\Script.py as my arguments, but it gives me two errors: One from Python for Win32 saying that it could not load my script and an error saying that there was an error processing command line args.

Comment: If you are using ArcGIS, your python.exe may be in a location like this: "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\python.exe".  Make sure to verify you have the path to the executable correct in your .bat file.

Comment: I have my .exe now as "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\Pythonwin.exe".  All the other .exe paths I've seen have been much shorter.  Am I getting the path for this from the wrong source?  I am navigating to the program from Windows Explorer and copying the path from there.

Comment: Instead of using PythonWin perhaps you should use the Python (command line) which was installed with ArcGIS, this is the path most of the answers are referencing.

Comment: That seems to be it.  Sorry for being a total numbnut.  I am still having problems with task scheduler, but I have it set up now with the C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\python.exe in the program and the Script.py in the arguments, and it runs consistently when I am logged on to my computer.  Thank you.

Comment: The accepted answer is fine to run the script and IF you want to see the console running as well.  Use pythonw.exe if you want it to running silently.

https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I use the following settings to "Start a program" in the task scheduler. I find it best to use the full path to the Python executable to be safe.

Program/script: Full path to Python.exe, `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\python.exe`

Arguments: Name of script, `script.py`

Start in: Location of `script.py`, something like `C:\path\to\script`

Also, if you pass in arguments to your script, include those with the arguments section, separated by spaces, `script.py arg1 arg2 argn`

Comment: awesome. was stuck with this.

Comment: Hi Chad, I have tried the same but whenever I run the Task in Scheduler nothing happens. My locations are: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe , code.py , C:\Users\me\Downloads

Answer (score 5):

I have always set up simple batch files like this:

```
start C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\python.exe \\some_server\some_script.py
```

You'll just want to make sure the full path to the executable and script match exactly.  If the path has any spaces in in it, you'll need to wrap it in double quotes. (`" "`)

Comment: I think this is what I have now.  Program/script: "Python.exe" "\\serverconection\script.py"  Task Scheduler then asks me if I want to make the server connection into an argument, I decline, and then the task won't run.  If I do use the server connection as an argument though, the script will open but not run.