# Compress - ERROR 000837: The workspace is not the correct workspace type

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

Getting an error with a very simple compress script.

This script works perfectly fine within arcmap, but I want to make this into a scheduled recurring script.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"\\UNC PATH \dbconnection.sde"
arcpy.Compress_management(r"\\UNC PATH \dbconnection.sde")
```

Super simple. I've tried importing arceditor in order to set the product for ArcGIS Desktop standard, to no avail. I've also attempted to run:

```
arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management()
```

before setting env.workspace, but still doesn't work. I have also tried different variations of the UNC path, such as specifying parent folder in workspace and then only the .sde in the compress, etc...

All errors come out as the one in the title: ERROR 000837: The workspace is not the correct workspace type.

Comment: What does `arcpy.Exists` on the workspace you're using return? (just to rule out)

Comment: @DWynne arcpy.Exists comes out True

I recently just tried arcpy.ListUsers() on that workspace, and it came out with being unable to access that sde.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hate to answer my own question. But I found the culprit of the problem.

I had a co-worker copy over their python27 directory, which is the one specifically created by ArcDesktop during installation (I realized I had forgot mine had gotten uninstalled, and then reinstalled by a standard python27 install).

According to ESRI's help, you should just have to point your python installation to include site-packages from the ARCGISDesktop/arcpy, bin, and scripting directories. This doesn't seem entirely true. I noticed a difference in the python27/DLLs folder, where there were 3 files (all starting with nc*) that were arcpy related. I copied those from his directory to mine, and it now works perfectly.

Not sure what these files do, as I haven't taken the time to go through them. I'm also not sure why this would throw a workspace error, when it should throw something more specific to a file missing error.

Comment: Yeah, if you have an ESRI installation of Python, you're pretty much out of luck ever trying to install another version of Python on your machine...something will inevitably get screwed up, and you'll end up having to reinstall Arc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [letter r to process the string as raw](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), you will need to place it outside the quotation marks:

```
r"\\UNC PATH \dbconnection.sde"
```

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo. It is.

Answer (score 0):

This *might* be related to ArcPy needing to be run through ArcGIS.  I have found a couple other questions that may be able to help you out.

[Using ArcPy Outside of ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18781/using-arcpy-outside-arcmap)

[Running ArcPy Script in Task Scheduler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140110/running-python-script-in-task-scheduler-script-will-not-run)

Comment: @ MaryBeth. Thanks for these. I ran across these when trying to troubleshoot the problem. You are able to use ArcPy outside of ArcGIS, however, as those posts show, it can be quite the pain. I ended up solving the issue, but thanks for the help!